# Hide Light From One Material But Not From Another Material On a Single Object

Tags: materials, lighting

I have a single object that has a logo that should be glossy and reflect light. The other material on the object is a matte finish, but still has slight glossiness to it. I would like to show off the glossy logo by having a light reflected in only the gloss material, but not show in the matte material on the same object. You can see in the reference image below that the matte material still reflects the light used to show off the gloss material:
[image]

I'm fairly new to Blender and using v2.8, but I've searched around quite a bit for this and can only find answers that suggest using light groups or compositing, but I'm trying to accomplish this using Cycles and everything I've seen is a very old post from 2017 or older saying Cycles can't do this. Surely this is not still the case as this is very easy to achieve in Cinema 4D?

Comment: Anyone? Bueller? Bueller?

Comment: Ok, can anyone suggest another forum/site to receive help specifically for Blender 2.8 at least?